# Correctly right-align a toggle and its labels

Tags: html, css

(I re-edit the question following the comment of Naga Sai A)

The following code shows a toggle description (on the left), the toggle and its labels (on the right) in one line:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/fabric/1.0/fabric.components.min.css">
  </head>
  <body class="ms-font-m">
    <div class="padding">
    <div class="ms-Toggle">
      <span class="ms-Toggle-description" style="display:inline; float:left;"><font size="3">Activate / Deactivate</font></span>
      <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" class="order ms-Toggle-input"> 
      <label for="toggle" class="order ms-Toggle-field" style="display:inline; float:right;">
        <span class="order ms-Label ms-Label--off">Off</span>
        <span class="order ms-Label ms-Label--on">On</span> 
      </label>
    </div>
    </div>  
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/miroju/17/edit?html,output).

However, we could see, from the output of JS Bin, the labels (ie, `off` or `on`) have past the right border:

[image]

Does anyone know what is the right way to make the toggle and its labels `right aligned`?

**PS:** I have tried to add `margin-right: 40px;` in `style="display:inline; float:right;"`, it did help. However, I really want to avoid constant `px` and find a good solution for exact `right-aligned`.

Comment: For those who voted `close`... WHY?

Comment: Probably because *Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].* But I could be wrong.

Comment: Well, my question is a **how to** question rather than debugging (no need to show lots of possibilities of code that does not solve this problem). And my statement and the JSBin is clear enough for this issue per se...

Comment: The key is "in the question itself". If jsbin goes down, this question becomes useless.

Comment: What do you mean by "jsbin goes down"?

Comment: Goes out of business, deletes all of the bins, whatever.

Comment: Guys, I just re-edited the question, please consider reopening it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that you have here is that you are using a css code (fabric.components.min.css) that adds the margin to your elements and "push" them outside their container element.

In order to "fix" this you can either add these elements the opposite margin (to move them back to their original place):

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/fabric/1.0/fabric.components.min.css">
  </head>
  <body class="ms-font-m">
    <div class="padding">
    <div class="ms-Toggle">
      <span class="ms-Toggle-description" style="display:inline; float:left;"><font size="3">Activate / Deactivate</font></span>
   <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" class="order ms-Toggle-input"> 
   <label for="toggle" class="order ms-Toggle-field" style="display:inline; float:right; margin-right: 17px">
     <span class="order ms-Label ms-Label--off">Off</span>
     <span class="order ms-Label ms-Label--on">On</span> 
   </label>
    </div>
    </div>  
  </body>
</html>
```

Or make the elements absolutely positioned, relatively to another container element:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/fabric/1.0/fabric.components.min.css">
  </head>
  <body class="ms-font-m">
    <div class="padding">
    <div class="ms-Toggle" style="position: relative";>
        <div style="position: absolute; left: 0;">
            <span class="ms-Toggle-description" style=""><font size="3">Activate / Deactivate</font></span>  
        </div>
        <div style="width: 90px; position: absolute; right: 0;">
              <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" class="order ms-Toggle-input"> 
              <label for="toggle" class="order ms-Toggle-field" style="">
                <span class="order ms-Label ms-Label--off">Off</span>
                <span class="order ms-Label ms-Label--on">On</span> 
              </label>
          </div>
    </div>
    </div>  
  </body>
</html>
```

Note that even if you used the absolute position - you still have to give the right container a width in order to keep it "inside" your viewport.

Answer (score 1):

add display:inline in your CSS

```
            <span style="display:inline" class="ms-Toggle-description">
```

Comment: And what about `right-aligned` the checkbox and labels?

Comment: <span style="display:inline;padding-left:1000px" class="ms-Toggle-description">..check updated code in codepen url

Comment: Sorry, I mean `left-align` the description, and `right-align` the checkbox and labels. Also I would prefer not to use a fixed length like `1000px`...

Comment: <span style="display:inline;float:left" class="ms-Toggle-description"><font size="3">Activate / Deactivate</font></span>
 <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" class="order ms-Toggle-input"> 
 <label for="toggle" style="display:inline;float:right"class="order ms-Toggle-field">

Comment: i just float: left and right and it fixed..i hope it works for you now :)

Comment: Your URL is not what I am after... I have totally re-edited the question, please vote reopen to attract more attention...

Comment: make left:50% to 90% ...position:relative;left:90%..i was not able to save changes in JSBin...but it works..i tried just now

Comment: Just press `cmd+S` or `Ctrl+S` to save in JSBin, and you will see a number in the URL...

Comment: yes..check jSBin URL now..i made it 80% and it looks good for me..hope it works for you :)   http://jsbin.com/yasuce/edit?html,output

Comment: `80%` is still a constant number, which is like `margin-right: 40px;`, but maybe there is no perfect solution... Thank you very much anyway...

Comment: 80% is constant but it is not fixed px value and adjusts based on the percentage mentioned....If you are fine with solution....can you mark it as answered?

Comment: Could we wait a little bit? If there is no other better comment, i will surely make it as an answer... Thank you again...

Comment: sure..Thanks alot SoftTimur